# Vue MultiSelect -- how to let user add new name that doesn't exist in the data list?

Tags: vuejs2, vue-multiselect

I am using a "type and search" plugin called [Vue-Multiselect](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started) to give the user the ability to search for a customer name in database. If the name exists in the database/drop-down list they can then select that name and it will auto populate the field(s).

**However, if the name doesn't exist, how can I give the user the ability to type the new name into the field? Scenario: *The user wants to add a new name that doesn't exist in the database*** Note: I do have an ApiService that I will POST to on form submission.

> Here's my template code (also available in [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ea8p620w/9/)):

```
<multiselect 
    v-model="customer_last_name" 
    :options="options"
    placeholder="Select an existing customer or type to add a new one"
    :custom-label="customerSelectName"
    label="lastname"
    track-by="uid"
    :close-on-select="true" 
    :clear-on-select="false" 
    :hide-selected="true" 
    :preserve-search="true"  
    id="example"
    @select="onSelect"
  >
  </multiselect>

<!--           <label for="customer_first_name_input">First Name:</label><br>
          <input id="customer_first_name_input" type="text" v-model="customer_first_name" /> -->
```

> Script:

```
new Vue({
    components: {
    Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
    },
    data: {
    customer_last_name: '',
    customer_first_name: '',
    options: [{"uid":"1","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","email":"johndoe@aol.com","phone":null,"c_organization":"ACME","c_title":null}, {"uid":"2","firstname":"Mary","lastname":"Smith","email":"msmith@aol.com","phone":null,"c_organization":"NBA","c_title":"Miss"}]
    },
  methods: {
    customerSelectName (option) {
      return `${option.lastname}, ${option.firstname}`
    },
    onSelect (option, uid) {
        console.log(option, uid)
    }
  }
}).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `vue-multiselect` library allows this with the `tags` functionality.

you need to add `:taggable="true" @tag="addTag" :multiple="false"`

and add an addTag method:

```js
addTag (newTag) {
  const parts = newTag.split(', ');

  const tag = {
    uid: this.options.length + 1,
    firstname: parts.pop(),
    lastname: parts.pop()
  };
  this.options.push(tag);
  this.customer_last_name = tag;
}
```

This is just a sample method that would convert input `Chavez, Martha` into:

```
{
  "uid": 3,
  "firstname": "Martha",
  "lastname": "Chavez"
}
```

You may want to update that function to better suit your needs

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/dapo/nwvpd4m2/

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I'll give this a try asap and report back.

Comment: Thanks again, it works. I had a follow up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58750770/vue-multiselect-how-to-autopopulate-rest-of-input-fields-after-first-selection