# Vue-Multiselect: How to autopopulate rest of input fields after first selection made?

Tags: vue.js, vue-multiselect

I am using [**Vue-Multiselect**](https://vue-multiselect.js.org/#sub-getting-started) plugin and want to know how I can auto populate additional input fields (`customer_firstname` and `customer_email`) when a user selects an item from the initial drop down?

**Scenario:** If the name exists in the database/drop-down list the user can then select that name and Vue will auto populate the rest of the input fields (taken from the `options` array). Else, if the name does not exist, the user can tag/create a new value for each additional input fields (e.g, `customer_firstname`, `customer_email`).

Here's my [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/doss1/oqvLm9wd/24/) code with evertying working, ***just need help wiring up the ability to autopopulate the rest of the input fields based on the initial selection of the `lastname` dropdown.***

> Vue Template:

```html
    <div id="app">
      <div>
        Last Name:
        <multiselect id="dontforget" v-model="customer_last_name" :options="options" placeholder="Select an existing customer or type to add a new one" label="lastname" :custom-label="customerSelectName" track-by="uid" :close-on-select="true" :clear-on-select="false" :hide-selected="true" :preserve-search="true" @select="onSelect" :taggable="true" @tag="addTag" :multiple="false" tag-placeholder="Add customer as new customer">
          <template slot="singleLabel" slot-scope="props">{{ props.option.lastname }}</template>
          <template slot="option" slot-scope="props">
            <span style="font-weight: bold;">{{ props.option.lastname }}</span>, {{ props.option.firstname }} -- <small>{{props.option.email}}</small>
          </template>
          <template slot="noResult">no rsults brah</template>
        </multiselect>
        <pre class="language-json"><code>Data: {{ customer_last_name  }}</code></pre>
        <br>
        <br>
        <br>
        <label for="customer_first_name_input">First Name:</label><br>
        <input id="customer_first_name_input" type="text" v-model="customer_first_name" />
        <br>
        <label for="customer_emailt">Email:</label><br>
        <input id="customer_email" type="email" v-model="customer_email" />
      </div>
    </div>
```

> Vue Script:

```js
    new Vue({
        components: {
        Multiselect: window.VueMultiselect.default
        },
        data: {
        customer_last_name: '',
        customer_first_name: '',
        customer_email: '',
        options: [{"uid":"1","firstname":"John","lastname":"Doe","email":"johndoe@aol.com","phone":null,"c_organization":"ACME","c_title":null}, {"uid":"2","firstname":"Mary","lastname":"Smith","email":"msmith@aol.com","phone":null,"c_organization":"NBA","c_title":"Miss"}, {"uid":"3","firstname":"Mike","lastname":"Verlander","email":"asdafsdf@aol.com","phone":null,"c_organization":"MLB","c_title":"Mr"}]
        },
      methods: {
        addTag (newTag) {
          const parts = newTag.split(', ');

          const tag = {
            uid: this.options.length + 1,
            firstname: parts.pop(),
            lastname: parts.pop()
          }
          this.options.push(tag)
          this.customer_last_name = tag;
        },
        customerSelectName (option) {
          return `${option.lastname}, ${option.firstname}`
        },
        onSelect (option, uid) {
            console.log(option, uid)
        }
      }
    }).$mount('#app')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You pretty much have everything you need. Your method `onSelect` is appended to the `select` event of your multiselect, so you can just use it.

In your `onSelect` method, add these lines:

```
this.customer_first_name = option.firstname;
this.customer_email = option.email;
```

That will assign to your variables the properties of the object you get when you select an option.